# Show tags for each post in list without using too many queries

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have a MySql database posts filled with posts that are displayed on browse.php in a list, limit ten per page.

I have two separate tag database tables, `tags` (id, tag) and `tagRel` (tagId, postId) that contain the tags, and I'm trying to figure out a better way to show the tags for each individual post in browse.php without running a separate query each time to get the tags for each individual post.

So right now I have something like this

```
SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 10
```

and then in the results loop

```
SELECT * FROM tags 
INNER JOIN tagRel ON tagRel.tagId = tags.id 
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = tagRel.postId 
WHERE posts.id = :currentId
```

This works, but doesn't seem like the most efficient way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ItayGal it works but that's 10x queries. I think the rdesilva is the correct.

Answer (score 2):

For every page you want to display 10 posts, then instead of doing 10 queries to get tags, execute the following query to get tags for all 10 posts at one. And for better performance, you can avoid the join to `posts` table

```
SELECT * FROM tags INNER JOIN tagRel ON tagRel.tagId = tags.id WHERE tagRel.postId in (postId1, postId2, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*, t.* FROM posts as p, tags as t, tagRel as tr WHERE p.id = tr.postId and tr.tagId=t.id limit 10
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT B.*, (SELECT group_concat(tags) from tags where post_id = B.id) as tags FROM posts AS B;